# Multi Events Combination

Tags: dice

4 identical dice rolled at the same  time 
what  is the number of the possibility to have exactly  two 1's  ?

somehow i don t find the correct  answer between these :

(1):

since it is " at the same time "  then  the order plays no role here 
then  we have

1122

1123

1124

1125

1126

1133

1134

1135

1136

1144

1145

1146

1155

1156

1166

==> there number of possibility is 15

(2)

since it is " at the same time "  then  the order plays no role here 
then  we have 
11xx   and x in [2,6] 
Then the  number of the possibility would be $\binom{2+5-1}{2} = \binom{6}{2} =30 \neq 15 $ !! 
what was  worng !

Comment: How is $\binom 62=360$?

Comment: because  it does not matter  which one is  the  first  or the last

Comment: $\binom{6}{2}$ is equal to $15$. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6+combination+2

Comment: I removed that part of my comment because it is specified that the dice are identical.

Comment: $\binom{6}{2} = \frac{6!}{4!} = 30 $ ?

Comment: @MedAyssarBenelhedi That formula is used for permutations. Combinations are given by: $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}=\frac{6!}{4!\cdot 2!}$

Comment: oh yeah i remember now  !! my bad !! i guess i have to take a rest

Comment: yeah you  are  right  ! yeah , just  got  confused about many things , sorry

Comment: yeah sure , both ways i found  the same  result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only mistake is that $\binom{6}{2}$ does not equal to $30$.
The formula you used is for permutations:
$$^{r+n-1}P_r=\frac{(r+n-1)!}{(r+n-1-r)!}=\frac{(r+n-1)!}{(n-1)!}=\frac{6!}{4!}=30$$
But what you should be looking for is:
$$^{r+n-1}C_r=\binom{r+n-1}{r}=\frac{(r+n-1)!}{(r+n-1-r)!r!}=\frac{(r+n-1)!}{(n-1)!r!}=\frac{6!}{4!\cdot 2!}=15$$

Comment: more accurate was $ \binom{r+n-1}{r}$

Comment: I guess for other people who may read this  , would be better  to give them the accurate version